# Polymer paper-fab display square mask in mobile

Tags: css, polymer, material-design, web-component

I have a paper-fab on my index page and it is displaying right until I tap on it. I say tap because this behavior only occours in mobile environment (in the chrome mobile view or on my Nexus 5).

This is the active button (on tap):

[image: Tapped button]

Note that the background is light gray. This square around the button is what I want to remove. The button is perfectly round. But this thing appears when tapped.

I tested other applications, like Topeka, and the active button (on tap) displays right:

[image: Topeka button]

But aparently there's nothing in special between my paper-fab and Topeka's one.

Here's the element declaration and the CSS:

```
<paper-fab icon="add" id="add-button"></paper-fab>

paper-fab#add-button {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #3F51B5;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Is there something wrong?

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your silver bullet is:

```
body {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

I suggest also that you attended to specify `shim-shadowdom` parameter for your `style` declaration:

```
<style shim-shadowdom>
```

BTW, you might want to compare your code against official [`paper-fab` docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/paper-elements.html#paper-fab) rathen than topeka.

Hope it helps.